# Append columns to a SQL db from a list from python with unique column names

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I apologize if my question is unclear, I don't really know how to ask this.  However, I'll do my best to articulate myself here.

I have a hand written digit interpreter and when my model gets the prediction wrong I want to send the data to a SQL db (I use postgres) and have that database grow as I send it more data.  The problem I think I have is that as I run my program and it sends the data and I restart my program, I can't think of how to make the data have unique column names so I can call on certain data easier.  My data is essentially just lists of length 7057.  I've tried to put them into a pandas df and that works fine except for the problem I'm having with unique column names.

If this needs any clarification please comment and I'll do my best to clarify, I didn't think the addition of any of my code would clarify, so I didn't add any.

Thank you for your help,

Jackson

Given some data from my interpreter this is what I want to happen.

```
rds_connection_string = "postgres:password@localhost:5432/digit_recognizer_db"
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{rds_connection_string}')

data = listofthings
def myApp():
    X_data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [some column name],data) #(or something)
     X_data_df.to_sql(name='new_training_table',con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
```

... And whenever I run this I need the column name to be unique in SQL. If this is better done with another database language I can do that, I'm not married to the idea of doing this on SQL.

I'm trying to make it so I can continuously update a SQL database with new data that has arbitrary but different column names.

Comment: it would be great if you add your code

Comment: I'll try to write some psuedo code about what I want to do but its not like I'm trying something and it's not working I just don't know how to do this thing.